# How to use a cursor for populating stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to use a cursor for retrieving the result from stored procedure. Please look following stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
@ID INT
AS 
BEGIN

        DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(400);
        DECLARE ACursor CURSOR FOR EXEC AStoredProcedure @ID

    OPEN ACursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM ACursor INTO @Name;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT @NAME
        END
    CLOSE ACursor;
    DEALLOCATE ACursor;

END
```

I have got the error with this. But I want to use like this. How can I do this?

PS. I can't INSERT EXEC statement for stored procedure. Because the stored procedure already use this statement and I don't want to make any changes for this stored procedure.

Comment: **WHAT** error are you getting? Please - we're not mindreaders, nor can we see your screen. You need to **provide at least** the necessary bits for us to be able to help you!

Comment: I can suggest you to change your approach, for tables with volumes of data in the range of 1,000,000.....this approach would be dangerous

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a datatype for @ID
Possibly @ID INT

Comment: I am sorry for wrong code. I have changed it. Please check it.

Comment: How about something like this... create a temp table with the results from the stored procedure and then create the cursor from the temp table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296753/navigating-the-results-of-a-stored-procedure-via-a-cursor-using-t-sql

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to fetch next row inside the loop:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
@ID INT
AS 
BEGIN

        DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(400);
        DECLARE ACursor CURSOR FOR EXEC AStoredProcedure @ID

    OPEN ACursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM ACursor INTO @Name;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT @NAME
            FETCH NEXT FROM ACursor INTO @Name;
        END
    CLOSE ACursor;
    DEALLOCATE ACursor;

END
```

This should be rewritten as:

```
    OPEN ACursor;
    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM ACursor INTO @Name;

        IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        BEGIN
            BREAK
        END
        PRINT @NAME
    END
    CLOSE ACursor;
    DEALLOCATE ACursor;
```

This way you only have one `fetch` in your code. Now it is not easy to forget about it, nor you have to append a column added to cursor query to each fetch separately.

Cursors are evil but sometimes necessary. To speed them up use `fast_forward` and `static` keywords, and use `local` so that an error in code does not leave open cursor behind.